# update using increments in mysql return duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

so I run

```
UPDATE x
SET y = y + 1;
```

where y is a primary key for the table...but then suppose there are two entries in the table with y = 1,2,3...the query will complain about duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' since when it tries to update the one with y = 1 to y = 2, it'll conflict with the other already existing entry with y = 2...is there a way to make mysql ignore this and just update everything anyway without manually removing the key....I know that I can just remove key temporarily and then execute this then re-add the key but I'm wondering if it's possibly to do this without doing so...

Comment: Hm, why would you want to do that? :)

Comment: how about searching for the problem keys and then only fixing those?  are you really asking to just adjust all keys to key+1?

Comment: @Randy yes..............

Comment: Keep in mind that if this is a master table to a detail table, every realtion will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
UPDATE x SET y = y + 1 order by y DESC
```

Comment: or maybe a 2 pass update - where you add some number larger than the largest existing key to every key.. then on pass 2 you subtract back down to 1 more than that..